# Excel ribbon in VSTO that interract with a COM adding in excel

Tags: excel, vsto, ribbon

I am trying to interact with another com addin in excel.  I can write the code in an addin in Excel and I know all the things I need to accomplish.  Again, I can do this in Excel VBA, but I want to create a DLL with my code so it is a little more secure.  So, I am moving to VS but I can't, for the life of me, find any way to interact with that model.  I would think there would be a way to call a function from VS the same way you can in Excel VBA.  Anybody have any thoughts on this, have a way to do it, or have an example I could use?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx

Comment: It's not quite clear from your post - you have 2 addins, and both are yours (you can modify both), and you want to call Addin1 from Addin2?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far.  The addin I am trying to interact with is a 3rd party addin from Oracle.

Comment: Sub CallVSTOMethod()  
    Dim addIn As COMAddIn  
    Dim automationObject As Object  
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ExcelImportData")  
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object  
    automationObject.ImportData  
End Sub  
Based on this, which I understand, how do I find the correct name/string for the addin?  Is it the dll name?

Comment: in the example ExcelImportData, is this the name of the addin file, the name of the adding you see in Excel, or something else?